# Why doesn't Server.TransferRequest work in MVC when outside a controller action?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7.5

I'm stumped as to why Server.TransferRequest doesn't seem to be working in MVC when you are outside a controller action method.  To showcase this issue, I've made a new, completely empty ASP.NET MVC 4 project, with one 'home' controller that has 2 actions: 'Wrong', and 'Right'.  What I want to do is detect when someone is going to 'Wrong' and issue a Server.TransferRequest to 'Right', and I need to do it inside the 'Application_BeginRequest' event.  This code causes a 404:

```
    protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Path.ToLower().Contains("wrong"))
        {
            // this causes a 404 (note the application is hosted as a 
            // virtual app under 'cool')
            Server.TransferRequest("/cool/home/right", true);
        }
    }
```

But when I do it inside the 'Wrong' controller action method, it works fine:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Wrong()
    {
        // this works
        Server.TransferRequest("/cool/home/right");
        
        return View();
    }


    public ActionResult Right()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

In debugging this issue, I turned on failed request tracing, and found that the second time through the pipeline in the unsuccessful case, I see this:

[image]

And I'm wondering why it is switching to a 'StaticFile' handler.  After seeing this, I turned on the setting runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests='true', which makes it work!  Unfortunately, I can't use this setting in my project.  Another thing I've found is that it will work if you are trying to Server.TransferRequest to an .aspx file.

Anybody got ideas?

Comment: i think that you should use server.transfer in attribute, not in action